# Facebook Graph API Page's Ratings user Id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to get Page's reviews using graph API with page's access token, and I get only info below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "created_time": "2018-08-03T11:50:18+0000",
      "rating": 5,
      "review_text": "Test Review about page"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "MTAwMDE5NDc4NTg5OTYyOjE5Nzc5MTQ0ODg5MzMxMTAZD",
      "after": "MTAwMDE5NDc4NTg5OTYyOjE5Nzc5MTQ0ODg5MzMxMTAZD"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any solution for get user's facebook_id from /ratings?

UPD:
I also tried enable all fields in graph api explorer (open_graph_history, has_rating, reviewer), but the answer is not contain reviewer's id.
Maybe I should some permission to page/app?

Which permission should I have for access to reviewer field?

Comment: did you ask for it with the fields parameter? btw, please only include relevant tags. the node.js tag is not relevant if you do not present any node.js code in your question. you SHOULD present the relevant parts of your code though.

Comment: What do you need user ID for?

Comment: @WizKid I use user ID for interacting reviews about page and my messenger bot.

Comment: What does that mean? You going to message people that review your page?

Comment: @WizKid No that is for saving information of user, that reviewed page. Please help me undestand, why field "reviewer" is blank

Comment: Most likely because there is no reason for you to have it. You still haven't explained what you need it for

Comment: @WizKid today /ratings api is changed? I get blank data: [] in my requests, whats happened?